Inverse Series of $x\sin x$
For some background before I get into my question: I am a Calculus 2 student who knows only some of the bare essentials to Complex Analysis, so bear with me.
I was recently studying the transformation of series into their inverse counterparts (after being inspired by the effectiveness of the Lambert $W$ function), and I decided to pick studying the function $x\sin x $.
Because the solution can't be expressed in closed form with only elementary functions, I decided to settle on determining the Taylor Series for the function. After some research, I stumbled upon Series Reversion, which Wolfram's website provided as an intuitive solution to my problem.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html
With some functions, this method provides an interesting way to approximate their inverses (such as for $x\cos x$). However, you will notice an issue with the formula becomes clear when trying to plug in a series with an $a_1$ coefficient of $0$. i.e.
$$A_1 =  a_1^{-1} =  0^{-1}$$
Which just so happens to be the case for the series I was trying to find. Nevertheless, when one solves for the inverse series on Mathematica using the aptly titled InverseSeries function, you get this:
$$F(x)=\sqrt x + \frac {x^{3/2}}{12} + \frac {29x^{5/2}}{1440} + \frac {263x^{7/2}}{40320} + O(x^{9/2}).$$
I find it quite interesting that this power series contains only fractional powers of $x$ as well, which has only deepened my curiosity. How would you go about finding this solution?

Solution to what?  You have the expansion, is that not good enough?

@user619894 Yes, but now I've become more curious on HOW you would find the solution and why a power series would have fractional powers in the first place. I mean, what's the fun in finding a solution if you don't know how to get there!

try  to invert $y=x^2$

See Extended Inversion Theorem in https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.10#vii

I assume that $x\ge 0$ is sufficiently small. By power series expansion
$$
y = x\sin x = x^2  - \frac{{x^4 }}{6} +  \ldots  = x^2 \left( {1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{6} +  \ldots } \right).
$$
Taking square roots on both sides gives
$$
y^{1/2}  = x\left( {1 - \frac{x^2}{6} +  \ldots } \right)^{1/2}  = x\left( {1 - \frac{x^2}{{12}} +  \ldots } \right) = x - \frac{{x^3 }}{{12}} +  \ldots\,.
$$
Now you can revert for $x$ in powers of $y^{1/2}$. This will yield the result given by Wolfram Mathematica.

How is $x\left( {1 - \frac{x^2}{6} +  \ldots } \right)^{1/2}  = x\left( {1 - \frac{x^2}{{12}} +  \ldots } \right)?$

Plug in $z=-\frac{x^2}{6}+\ldots$ into the standard Maclaurin series of $\sqrt{1+z}$ and expand the result in powers of $x$.

Ah I see, very clever. Thank you for clearing that up.

If you think I answered your question, feel free to accept it.
